# Setup react-routing with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, routes, url-routing

I am newbie for React, I know rails, I have created basic `React` application that perform CRUD operation.

Now, I tried to implement routing with react and want to redirect a page after successful login.

I have used `gem 'react-rails'` and `gem 'react-router-rails'` in my app.

Please instruct me with basic step to setup react route.

Thanks in advance.